# Site design and Product type to create

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, color-swatches

I’m trying to build a site with CE v1.9.1 that will allow users to select and configure a customized DVD on-screen menu from 41 choices, then change the look of that menu by changing things like the menu’s Chapters (41 choices) and navigation buttons (50 choices).

The next customer step would be select a DVD Label that would applied to it and it’s case from 146 pre-configured ones or choose one of 386 backgrounds that we would configure. We will then use their choices to create the finished Burned / Labeled DVD with their content on it for them.

I’m assuming that Configurable Products and Swatches are the way to go but any suggestions would be appreciated. I should add, I’ve created over 4700 1123x841 .jpg’s as possible customer choices for the Menu’s options plus 532 1120x807 .jpg’s for Label’s. I hope they can be somehow used as Swatch images.

I’ve installed v1.9.1 and think I’m at the point of creating my 1st configurable product. I started by creating some Attributes but don’t really know how detailed they have to be or quite how to structure them or if this is the correct order of the steps involved etc. I seem to be going in circles reading the manual and Magento site.

I want the customer’s flow of the site after creating their account to be as follows:

- Pick one of (41) available on-screen Menus (each one it’s own Configurable Product with images), leave it Default or change the Chapter Frames and / or Navigation Buttons.
- Select one of 146 pre-configured Label designs or one of 386 backgrounds we make the decisions on.
- Add any additional instructions for their completed product and their finished

So here are the questions... I think.

1. Should I be proceeding with Configurable Products or would one of the other product types be better.
2. How do I create a Configurable Product with this many options (what are the steps in their correct order)
3. Does each of the 41 DVD menus require it’s own set of Attributes i.e.: 41 Chapters x 50 Nav Buttons
4. When it comes time to create the Label I’m not sure which product type or how to lay out presentation on the site that would best provide the customer with the 532 options just yet.

***Moderator Edit: Flynn, here's your response which you posted as an edit to Pakicle's answer (this is not proper on StackExchange):***

> Thanks so much for the response Pakicle. I’ve come to the realization I’ll be 100 years doing this so I switched gears.. As I mentioned, I find Magento confusing for the average guy (me) and have 1 more question if you don’t mind. Let me explain:
>
> **Step 1.** I want to have the customer select 1 product (a menu) from 42 individually displayed products, in either a DVD (eg:$15.00) or Blu-Ray (eg:$18:00) format. (I did this with a configurable Product)
>
> Now I don’t know how to proceed, I don’t think a configurable product or bundled product will work to do the rest.
>
> **Step 2.** I want the customer to be forced to a part 2 before they checkout where they have to pick a Label from (143 Designs) or (386 Backgrounds) to complete the process. There are too many Labels to display as 1 large group so I want to display the Labels as images in similar groups where eg: all the outdoor scenes, styles including squares, wavy designs, circles, etc. would be displayed separately, the customer would browse through the groups to make their Label choice and any special instructions they may have to finish the process prior to checkout. **I don’t want to have to add 143 + 386 simple products 42 times.**
>
> **Step 3.** Checkout
>
> So to summarize, the customer would add a menu, 1 of 42 in either DVD or Blu-Ray to their cart, then be re-directed to another page where they would have to pick a label before they check-out.

Answer (score 1):

For the on Screen-Menu:

1. Create two attribute - i)Menu-Chapter and ii)navigation button, create all the possible value for them (which should be 41 and 50 possible choice)
2. Create a attribute-Set with this two attribute
3. Associate this configurable product with simple product, would should have 41x50 = 2050 products.

For the label:

1. An option out of the 146+386=532 images customer can choose from. (if you mean "mixing" the pre-configurable ones(?) and the backgrounds then it would give 146x386=56356 images)

I suggest separating the above into 2 products (related product). otherwise this would be a configurable product with 3 options providing 2050x532=1,090,600 product/images!

Note: I am not sure whether Magento 1.9.1 support multiple swatch both can swap images, but there are Swatch extension can do this.